# A stranger problem about QTimer::singleShot

Tags: qt

I wrote a function calling QTimer::singleShot to make sure it should not be timeout.  But I got a stranger result.

```
int Test(int x)
{
    QEventLoop loop;

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
        loop.exit(x);
    });
    timer.start(7000);

    QTimer::singleShot(10000, std::bind(&QEventLoop::exit, &loop, 3));

    return loop.exec();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    qDebug() << Test(1) << endl;
    qDebug() << Test(2) << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I expect the output to be 
1
2
but the actual output is
1
3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like undefined behaviour.  With regard to *why* you might be seeing the symptoms as described, consider your implementation of `Test`...

```
int Test(int x)
{
    QEventLoop loop;

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
        loop.exit(x);
    });
    timer.start(7000);

    QTimer::singleShot(10000, std::bind(&QEventLoop::exit, &loop, 3));

    return loop.exec();
}
```

You construct a local `QEventLoop`.  You then set up two timer callbacks (after 7s and 10s) that *both* exit the local event loop.  The first timeout will exit the loop causing `Test` to finish and return.  But there is still a timeout pending which will also try to exit the now invalid `QEventLoop`.  When you call `Test` again as `Test(2)` there is a strong probability that the new `QEventLoop` will be constructed at the same address as for the previous call to `Test`.  The net result being that the `QEventLoop` address used by the still pending timeout becomes ``valid''.  Hence, the two values you see are actually from the two timeout events from the call to `Test(1)`.

As I said at the start though -- undefined behaviour.